# angular ng-options directive ends up selecting multiple items

Tags: html, angularjs

In AngularJS page I have a dropdown that lists buildings (facilities):

```
<select ng-model="selectedFacility"
   ng-options="facility.abbr for facility in facilities track by facility.id">
</select>
<label>{{selectedFacility.name}}</label>
```

*Seems* to be working. The value in the dropdown shows what user selects (abbreviation), and the text in the label shows corresponding long name. Good.

However, elsewhere I pass `$scope.selectedFacility.id` to `$http` call and I noticed that it is always 1, regardless what building is actually selected. I looked deeper (in Chrome F12), and I see that **all** dropbox items that I selected at some point have `selected="selected"` attribute:

```
<option value="1" label="Engineering" selected="selected">Engineering</option>
<option value="2" label="Biology" selected="selected">Biology</option>    
<option value="3" label="CompSci">CompSci</option>    
<option value="4" label="Admissions" selected="selected">Admissions</option>    
<option value="5" label="Security">Security</option>
```

As is clear from the output above, I selected items 1, 2, and 4 *at some point*. My guess is that since first item was selected initially, it ends up always having "selected" attribute, and therefore `selectedFacility.id=1`. But how do I tell Angular to remove selected attribute? It is a regular dropdown, without any way to select multiple items - yet multiple items get marked as selected

**UPDATE**. It looks like it is important that the controller has the following:

```
$scope.selectedFacility= {};
$scope.facilities = facility.getFacilities().query(function(facilities) {
  $scope.selectedFacility=facilities[0];
});
```

and facility is provider service that retrieves facility information from the server:

```
  service.getFacilities = function() {
    return $resource(url);
  };
```

If I start using `$scope.selectedFacility.imeanit=facilities[0];` and `selectedFacility.imeanit` in ng-model, it works as expected

Comment: As I was writing the question, it occurred to me to try `selectedFacility.imeanit` rather than just `selectedFacility`. It seems to solve the problem. I remember that Javascript works that way with closures - but I would be curious to learn how it applies here...

Comment: I mocked up your example in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WznqxKg8kdrQua7gBYuf?p=preview) and it's working fine for me. Can you provide more details on the angular version you're using?

Comment: Interesting... I am using 1.4 (like you). Maybe the difference is that the list of facility objects is retrieved through provider service. That is, service.getFacilities = function() { return $resource(url); };

and in controller,

$scope.facilities = facility.getFacilities().query(function(facilities) { $scope.selectedFacility=facilities[0]; });

(I don't know if there is a more readable way to show code in SO comment

Comment: Could you please you update your question with the relevant parts of the controller & service (e.g. it'd be helpful to see what `getFacilities` returns & what `query` does)?

Comment: good point. `service.getFacilities()` brings JSON representation of the facilities - array of {id, abbr, name}. And query() doesn't do anything other than setting the first facility as selected, so there is no empty option in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

I was able to recreate your issue [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4CrVA5sqADDHFRL0WgYr?p=preview).

I setup a watch on `$scope.selectedFacility`, to see when the model actually updates.

```
$scope.$watch('selectedFacility', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log(newVal);
  console.log(oldVal);
});
```

The watch gets called once at the start:

```
[Log] null (main.js, line 17)
[Log] null (main.js, line 18)
```

Then once more inside the `query()` callback:

```
[Log] Resource (main.js, line 17)
    abbr: "Eng"
    id: 1
    name: "Engineering"
    __proto__: Resource
[Log] null (main.js, line 18)
```

But then never again, even when changing the selected option in the `<select>`.

The reason why has to do with how JS prototypal inheritance works, and the [implications of that](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) with 2-way bindings & Angular's ability to do dirty-checking when child scopes are involved (which are here, thanks to `ng-options`). [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) explains it well.

## The Fix

If you instead make `facilities` an object whose members are the list of `Resource`s and the selected `Resource`, then it will work. Here's [another plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nOTcB8nYOjXygvVSjfWJ?p=preview) showing a working example (relevant details below):

**JS:**

```
$scope.facilities = {
  selected: null,
  all: []
};

$scope.facilities.all = Facilities.query(function(list) {
  $scope.facilities.selected = list[0];
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-if="facilities.all.length"
        ng-model="facilities.selected"
        ng-options="facility.abbr for facility in facilities.all track by facility.id">
</select>
<label ng-if="facilities.selected">{{facilities.selected.name}}</label>
```

(strictly speaking, only the `ng-model` (i.e. `facilities.selected`) needs to be a property-of-a-property-of-`$scope`, but I thought the above structure was cleaner).